# How can I interleave an array in nlogn time?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I have been struggling with this for some time, I need to write a recursive function, that uses divide and conquer method to interleave an array, for example:

[1,2,3,4,a,b,c,d]

is turned to

[1,a,2,b,3,c,4,d].

I've searched the internet, but only found the solution when the number of elements in array is a power of 2. The transition has to be done in place, with nlogn time. Also, is it possible to be done when the number of elements is odd? I'm writing in java but will be grateful for any help.

Comment: 1) Is it one input array or can we have 2? 2) Why does your function need to be recursive? 3) Why does it need to be divide and conquer? If I had to write such linear algorithm, it would only take n steps, so I don't understand why you write things like that. Maybe a miconception of some kind? Got it mixed up with some sorting algorithm?

Comment: @JayC667 it's kind of an assignment, we're currently studying recursion and divide-conquer algorithms, there's only one input array

Comment: Then I'm sorry to say, but unless the divide-and-conquer algorithm is focused on multi-threading, it is a brutally bad idea to use it for this kind of task. Actually it's completely counterproductive. So the assignment is trash. The interleave problem is linear O(n). Using divide-and-conquer here will probably INCREASE complexity to O(n*log(n)) or even O(n²). divide-and-conquer splits big n's into a lot smaller fractions, to reduce the quadratic effect that n² would have. Using splitting and recursion for interleaving will create a lot more problems and runtime complexity and lead to bad code.

Comment: Must the input be the first half numeric and second half alphabetic? Are we sorting or shuffling the array? Please provide more input and expected output